# How to instantiate default implementation of Protocol fully defined by Extensions

Tags: swift, protocols, default, implementation, extends

Would you like to explain me what's wrong in this code? I'm trying to understand the protocols' default implementation

```
protocol Person {
  var name: String {get}
  func printName() -> String
}

extension Person {
  var name: String {
    return "Andrea"
  }
}

extension Person {
  func printName() -> String {
      return "\(name) bye bye"
  }
}

struct person: Person {} //correct

person.name  // error

person.printName() // error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing types and values.

`struct person` is a new *type* that *adopts* the `Person` protocol.

Now you need to define an instance.

This should be clearer:

```
protocol PersonProtocol {
    var name: String {get}
    func printName() -> String
}

extension PersonProtocol {
    var name: String {
        return "Andrea"
    }
}

extension PersonProtocol {
    func printName() -> String {
        return "\(name) bye bye"
    }
}

struct ConcretePersonType: PersonProtocol { } // correct

var personInstance = ConcretePersonType()

print(personInstance.name)  // No more error!

personInstance.printName() // No more error!
```

Answer (score 2):

You try to use static methods that not exist; make instance of struct instead:

```
struct Friend: Person {}

let friend = Friend()
print(friend.name)
friend.printName()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Protocols` are not data types. You are trying to use it as a data type in this line :

```
struct person: Person {}
```

Instead, you should use a `struct`/`enum`/`class` that conforms to a `protocol`.

In your case, the optimum solution would be to use `struct` :

```
struct PersonStruct: Person {}
let foo = PersonStruct()
print(foo.name)
foo.printName()
```